# Groupby in code or in database?

Tags: entity-framework, orm, group-by, relational-database

Is it better to be doing Groupby in code or in database?

I have a scenario where I have to groupby 6 different columns, and I am wondering what the preferred way of doing this is.

I know I should be filtering in the database than in code, but is this the same for GROUPBY clause?

Comment: groupby does minimize the data volume you receive by a large amount; if you suspect your db can deal with it well (depends a bit on DBMS), you should do as much as possible on server side.

Comment: Hi. Tell the DBMS as much as you can so it can optimize. This is a general principle in the use of the relational model. Read some intros to it. Also http://thehelsinkideclaration.blogspot.com/2009/03/start-of-this-blog.html Or gooling your title with 'stackoverflow' https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/171024) Learn to google. See [ask].

Comment: But scale-up the "code" is easier than scale-up a DB (web farm). Is it a valid reason to move some of the work away from the DB then? I'm only talking about `GroupBy` to organize the output dataset, not `GroupBy` for filtering or something, cause that definitely should be handle by the DB.